# Order by price, with a sort by column (not per line)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to rank the prices in ascending order, but the sorting is not done by line, but by column. One product per line, and each seller represents a column.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| title    | price_amazon  | price_bestbuy | price_seller3 | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| iPhone   |       699     |      899       |     759      |...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

max : 8 sellers

Result :

```
iPhone :
best price : XXX
2nd price : XXX
...
```

Thank you